# how can i make insert into table and overwrite if is not empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how can i make this code: if is not empty insert into table, else overwrite the rows:

```
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec( 
    "insert into table_1 (name, money, month, year)
    select name, count(*), MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y')),  
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    from table_2
    group by name");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (name, money, month, year)
SELECT t.name, t.money, t.month, t.year
FROM
(
    SELECT name,
           COUNT(*) AS money
           MAX(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y'))) AS month,
           MAX(YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y')))  AS year
    FROM table_2
    GROUP BY name
) t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=t.name, money=t.money, month=t.month, year=t.year
```

Note that I wrapped your calls to `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` with `MAX()`, an aggregate function, because it is incorrect to select a non aggregate column when using `GROUP BY`.  If you show us actual data for `table_2`, then perhaps this could be improved upon.

**Update:**

Note that the subquery whose result set is used for insertion above can never generate duplicate records, because there can only ever be a single record per group.  So to test this answer, you would already have to have some data in `table_1` which would be duplicated by the subquery.

Comment: Yes, but are you certain that it should be updating?  Are you inserting duplicate records?  Note that all four columns would need to be the same as a record already in `table_1`.

Comment: yes the records are the same as the first inserted. and is duplicating the rows with double values in money for ex: row 1: name: Test, 1200, 1, 2017 -- row 2: name: Test 2400, 1, 2017

Comment: No, this doesn't make any sense, the query could never return this.  There can only be _one_ record for each `name`.  If there is a name `Test`, then there can only be a _single_ record returned for that name.

Comment: You should review how `GROUP BY` works, your original query also has a logical problem using `GROUP BY`.